# Calling managed function inside CommandBuffer hang domain reload

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, mono

I'am trying to call managed function inside CommandBuffer via IssuePluginEventAndData. It accepts (void* function pointer, int eventId, void *data).
Here's the function:

```cs
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public unsafe delegate void PluginDelegate(int eventId, void* data);

[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(PluginDelegate))]
private static unsafe void MakeGraphicsCallback(int eventId, void* data)
{
    //Completely empty.
}
```

Then store delegate inside non-static MonoBehaviour class and add it to CommandBuffer:

```cs
//Prevent delegate to be garbage collected.
private static PluginDelegate makeCallbackDelegate;
public void Start()
{
    makeCallbackDelegate = MakeGraphicsCallback;
    cmdBuffer.IssuePluginEventAndData(
                    Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(makeCallbackDelegate),
                    0, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Everything works fine (even if function is not empty), but then, when game is stopped, and runned again it hang on domain reload, here's how editor log ends:

```
Reloading assemblies for play mode.
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
```

Then goes nothing, and the only way to make editor work again is to restart it.

I've also tried to call this function from my C++ native plugin function, and also tried to call it from C++ with different calling conventions (cdecl and stdcall explicitly stated in typedef, changed accordingly for UnamangedFunctionPointerAttribute):

```cpp
typedef void (__stdcall *PluginCallback)(int32_t eventId, void *data);
auto func = static_cast<PluginCallback>((void*)funcPtr);
func((int32_t)eventIdValue, (void*)dataValue);
```

Result is always the same.

When function is called from main thread -- everything goes fine, but once it called from another thread (unmanaged) by pointer -- assembly reload hangs forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. The thing is that if function pointer obtained by GetFunctionPointerForDelegate is called from non-managed thread, you need to first initialize a thread with `mono_attach_thread(domain)`.
So before calling function by pointer, you need to somehow call mono_attach_thread before, as stated in Mono Embedding Guide.

> If your application creates threads on its own, and you want them to be able to interact with Mono, you have to register the thread so that the runtime knows about it.
> To do so, call the mono_thread_attach() function before you execute any other Mono API or before manipulating any managed object.

Here's my workaround native plugin for this.
https://github.com/Meetem/ManagedRenderEvent